# How to email time-out notice from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: installation, google-cloud-storage, email, gsutil

I have a gsutil script that that periodically backs up data to Google Could Storage.
The gsutil backup script runs on my local box.
I would like to run a script (or service) on Google Could Storage, that emails a warning to the administrator when no backup has been made in 24 hours.

I am new to cloud services.  Please point me in the right direction.
Where would such a script be located?  Is there a similar example script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in feature that accomplishes this. However, you could accomplish something like this with another monitor program.

For example, I might edit my backup script such that after successfully completing a backup, it writes the current time to a "last_successful_backup.txt" file. Then, I'd put a cronjob wherever I keep my monitors and alerting systems that would check the "last_successful_backup.txt" file every few hours and set off an alarm if the time it contains is older than 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

What about to spin up Google VM and send emails from the instance? Using, say, SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet